# How to determine the distance between any two sites of a finite lattice subjected to periodic boundary conditions?

Tags: topology, ising-model, lattice-model

I want to study the Ising model on a finite kagome lattice assuming periodic boundary conditions (PBC) *and* long range interactions. More specifically, all spin pairs contribute to the total energy, so I should be able to determine all the neighbors of each spin.

I am labelling the spins as shown in the following figure, with three indices $(i, j, k)$, where $(i, j)$ are the coordinates of the unit cell and $k = 0, 1 \text{ or } 2$ the index within the cell.

[image]

My only issue is that I am having trouble to identify/visualize which are the distant neighbors of a given spin considering the PBC. Let us think about spin $(0, 0, 0)$, for definiteness. What I tried was to put copies of the lattice around, draw a circle centred at $(0, 0, 0)$ and see which spins are within that circle. This is depicted in the figure below (obs: I did it manually, so it is not super accurate, it is just for illutratration purposes). Due to the PBC, I've also drawn the circle around the spins $(0, 0, 0)$ of the copies. For a certain radius, the circles will touch for the first time (as shown in the figure). But you can see thre are still four spins out of the range of the circles. I can reach these spins by increasing the radius a little bit, but the circles will be overlapping, and this feels wrong to me.

[image]

So, in short, how do I find how far each spin of the lattice is from another one taking into account PBC? I stress that there is only one finite lattice, the copies I drew were just for visualization. I have never had to deal with this kind of situation, so I am not sure how to handle it. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a distance between any two sites labeled (i, j, k) and (m, n, l) for example, it seems to me that the answer is simply $|(m-i)\vec{v}_1 + (n-j)\vec{v}_2+ \vec{r}_{lk}|$, where $\vec{v}_1,\,\vec{v}_2$ are your unit cell vectors, and $\vec{r}_{lk}$ is vector that connects site with label "k" to site with label "l" in the same unit cell. I don't really know what you need this for, but if you want to implement it in software there shouldn't be any difficulties. EDIT : I'm not quite sure I understand exactly if this is even remotely close to the answer you're looking for, because I don't really see the idea you wanted to accomplish by sketching circles around sites.

Comment: The problem of just doing this is that it does not take into account PBC. For example, spin (3,0,2) is actually a first  nearest neighbor of (0,0,0), so the real distance between them is, say, 1. But your formula would give 7.

Comment: Oh, now I understand what you meant. Aren't then (0,0,0) and (3,0,2) actually the same, and not first neignbours? Anyway, if I come up with something I will post. I think the formula just needs slight modification then. EDIT : Yeah, they are first neighbours, not the same

Comment: I mean, one idea that comes to mind is to still use the same formula, but to calculate four different distances : one with (m,n), (m+4,n), with (m,n+4), and with (m+4,n+4) and then take the minimal of those 4. Of course, if m or n are greater than 1, then you would calculate for m-4/n-4, not m+4/n+4. It's not the most elegant method tho, and it's only really useful if you implement it in software.

Comment: Just a correction: I said (3,0,2) but I actually meant (3,0,1). (3,0,2) is actually a second neighbor, but anyway, you've got the point. I agree with you that considering the minimal distance seems to be the consistent way to deal with the situation, thank you. It makes intuitive sense to me, at least. But I still wanted a confirmation that this is really the standard way to handle it, because I'm afraid that might be some subtlety that makes our intuition wrong.

Comment: Hmm, I can't really say if this is the standard way. It is a right answer to your question. But I just don't see how a distance defined in such a way (that it takes PBC's into account) is relevant. Usually periodic boundary conditions are only important when you deal with wavefunctions.

Comment: The specific model I'm studying is one of spins interacting via dipolar interactions, which depends on the distance like ~1/r^3, so it is important to know this distance.

Comment: Okay, I've dealt with similar calculations (I was trying to calculate strength of interplanar interaction in certain systems caused by magnetic dipole-dipole interactions) so I have some experience in this. And I'm pretty sure you're supposed to use real distance (the one I gave in the first answer, not the one that takes PBC's into account).

Comment: Here, however, there are additional complications. In my system, every magnetic center had the same surrounding so I could calculate interaction of one of those with every other in some radius and just multiply the final result by N/2. At first glance it seems that your sites do not have the same surroundings so you have to take that into account. And because dipolar interaction is so long ranged you're supposed to take a lot of sites into account. You could first calculate for small radius (10 angstrom), and then subsequently increase it (maybe 100, 300, 1000) and check for convergence.

Comment: Sorry for spamming comments, but there's limit to characters. Anyways, you should check out this paper (if you have access) : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233807485_The_layered_ferromagnet_Cs2AgF4_Antiferromagnetic_inter-layer_coupling_driven_by_magnetic_dipole-dipole_interactions EDIT : P.S. It's not my paper :D